# How to create a consistent hashstring of a ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, zlib, digest

I wonder how it is possible to create a consistent hash of a ruby array full of strings. The requirements are that the hash is always the same if the array contains the same values, independent of their order.

```
>> a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>> SomeModule.hash(a)
=> "2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed"
>>
>> b = ["d", "b", "c", "a"]
>> SomeModule.hash(b)
=> "2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed"
>>
>> SomeModule.hash(a) == SomeModule.hash(b)
=> true
```

Zlib or digest only do strings, but I had to always sort the array and join it to get that working.

So is there anything better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just sort the array, concatenate all elements to a string and hash it.

```
def hash(array)
   Digest::SHA1.digest(array.join)
end
```

Comment: I see you last sentence now. But I'm not sure if you would come around sorting if the order of the elements should not matter.

Comment: If you convert your array to a set you are going to lose duplicate elements http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html. Don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: That's - in my case - even desired behavior, so that would be totally acceptable.

Comment: Seems, as with sort this is the only really "consistent" way how to do this.. so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your array to Set and call `to_set` method (don't foreget to `require 'set')

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
a.to_set.hash # => 425494174200536878

b = ["d", "b", "c", "a"]
b.to_set.hash # => 425494174200536878
```

Comment: Aah, that is a perfect solution thanks. Didn't know about the Set in Ruby. Fits perfectly!

Comment: Looks easy but you will lose duplicate array elements. That way `['a','b']` would be the same as `['a','b','a']`.

Comment: Is the `to_set.hash` method reliable to use here and will not change with other ruby 1.9 versions?

Comment: I just realized that the `.hash` method just represents a runtime hash and is not consistent during multiple runs. What would you suggest there?

Comment: Just unchecked this as the right answer, because unfortunately it isn't really consistent during multiple runs of the program..

Comment: The hash is consistent in a single process only.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a standard library called [`set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) that introduces the `Set` class. You can also easily implement it by yourself. Instead of an array like this:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

keep it as a hash:

```
{"a" => true, "b" => true, "c" => true, "d" => true}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the stateless aspect of `.hash` is being overlooked.  Running the following respects time sensitivity of this issue:

```
a = %w(alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot gulf hotel india july kilo sheep)
c = %w(alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot gulf hotel india july kilo sheep)

require 'ap'

ap a
ap c

def h2(value)
    Digest::SHA512.hexdigest value.inspect
end

aa = h2(a)
cc = h2(c)
ap aa
ap cc

ap "they are equal" if aa==cc
puts

t = Turtle.new("Tom", "blue")  # an object with two ivars, name and colour
ap h2(t)

t.name = "Teth"
ap h2(t)

t.name = "Tom"
ap h2(t)
puts

t.colour = "ruby red"
ap h2(t)

t.colour = "blue"
ap h2(t)
```